# Creating arrays / json objects, can't quite get this working

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, json, key

I have a rather complex situation that I need to get working, for some reason I am almost there but still not quite.

In PHP I create arrays and send to it javascript through json, I am quite sure that my problem is in this part of the code.

```
$insertIDs = array();

foreach($recipients as $userID)
{   
            //MySQL insert removed from question 
    $insertID = mysql_insert_id();
    array_push($insertIDs, $array[$userID] = $insertID);
}


$json = array();
$json['fromID'] = $session;
$json['insertIDs'] = $insertIDs;
    $json['recipients'] = $recipients;
echo json_encode($json);
```

when I console.log the results of this in javascript, I get:

```
{ messageID: 40,
  fromID: '1',
  insertIDs: [ 44 ],
  recipients: [ '3' ] }
```

Now in javascript when I try to access the insertIDs by the userID which I set it to be in the php above, I just get undefined as a result. How can I do this so I can access each insertID by the userID?

for example: `json.insertIDs[userID]`

if I simply call it by: `json.insertIDs[0]` it does return the first insertID, however when there are multiple I need to be able to have an easy way to access each usersID insertID.

Comment: You should probably be using the user ID as a key for the object, if that is how you intend to access it, otherwise I see a lot of iteration in your future.

Comment: That is what I have been trying to do, if you look at my php that's what it is suppose to do, but it doesn't appear that it is.

Comment: show us more of the javascript. Since you are getting a json response and it contains proper structure, php seems to be working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do, since in the forloop $insertID is always the same value but:

It seems like json.InsertIDs is an array of the form json.InsertIds = Array(44);

Where as you want it to be Array(3 => 44)

try changing your forloop from

```
foreach($recipients as $userID){   
$insertID = mysql_insert_id();
array_push($insertIDs, $array[$userID] = $insertID);
}
```

to

```
foreach($recipients as $userID){   
    $insertID = mysql_insert_id();
    $insertIDs[$userID] = $insertID;
}
```

Comment: Well in the for each loop $insertID actually is different, I just removed the MySQL query from my question, with it there it takes each userID and inserts it into the database thus generating a new of per loop. This does appear that it should work, I will give it a test soon. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the value returned by mysql_insert_id() would be the same every time, unless there was an INSERT query inside that foreach() loop.  Is part of the code missing?

Comment: Yes I removed the query from the question so it is different each time.